# Set Container class value from contained class

Tags: c#, class, oop

Sounds a simple question but haven't found a way to do, so would solicit any responses I get.

I have a winform which in turn contains a user control object. based on some condition in the user control, i have to set a value in the winform. 
One way could be to pass the winform object as parameter to user control but that would give cyclic dependency. Is there a easy way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use events from the user control to the form.

- [User Control Events in VB and C#](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/22/user-control-events-in-vb-and-c.aspx)
- [Writing C# Custom Events](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html)

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would expose an appropriate event from the usercontrol. The form can subscribe to the event and react accordingly.